# How to stop logging access log to stdout with Quart Python

Tags: python, logging, stdout, microservices, quart

I have microservice written in Quart python. I would like to stop logging on to stdout. So far I have tried app.logger.disabled = True and Flask alike 
import logging
log = logging.getLogger('werkzeug')
log.setLevel(logging.ERROR)

Havent achieved goals yet.

Answer (score 1):

In the snippet given the issue is that Quart has no `werkzeug` logger, it has `quart.app` and `quart.serving` so the likely equivalent is to do 
`logging.getLogger('quart.serving').setLevel(logging.ERROR)`

Note, this question was asked as a Quart [issue](https://gitlab.com/pgjones/quart/issues/130), and I am the Quart author.

Answer (score 1):

The following worked for me, with Quart 0.18.4:

```py
import logging
logging.getLogger('hypercorn.access').disabled = True
```

(I expected `logging.getLogger('hypercorn.access').setLevel(logging.ERROR)` to work too, but that strangely didn't do anything.)

Comment: This works! `logging.getLogger('quart.serving')` stopped working after I upgraded.